# Git me pide contraseña cada vez que envío a Github

Tags: git, windows10, powershell

Uso doble autenticación con GitHub, por lo tanto uso un *token* que funciona como contraseña, pero en [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) bajo [windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10), cada vez que ejecuto el comando `git push` o `git flow publish` me pide usuario y contraseña.

Tengo instalado el módulo [Posh-Git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git) y Git-Flow.

> **Nota adicional**
>   Tengo bloqueado el puerto 22 por lo que solo puedo usar el protocolo `https`.

#### Pregunta

¿Que debo hacer para que `git` no solicite más mi usuario y contraseña de GitHub?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Intenta con...

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Te solicitará las credenciales una vez y quedaran cacheadas para futuras operaciones.

[Referencia](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).